# Code has printed too many times repeatedly

Tags: python

```
myfile = open('Results.txt')
    title = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20}'.format('Player Nickname','Matches Played','Matches Won','Matches Lost','Points')
    print(title)
    unsorted_data = list()
    for line in myfile:
        item = line.split(',')
        points = int(item[2]) * 3
        item.append (points)
        if item[2] != 0:
            unsorted_data.append(item)
            sorted_data = sorted(unsorted_data,key=lambda x : x[5], reverse= True)
            for item in sorted_data:
                result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:<20}'.format(*item)
                print(result)
```

Hi there, I'm pretty new to python. So recently after asking another question on how to sort a list, I now have another problem. When the program prints my results it print a bunch of repeated names. How do I fix it? And is there a way to put .rstrip() into item[3] as there is a newline escape code there and I want to get rid of it. Together while sorting the list.

Below is an few examples from the file:

```
Esports,19,8,11
RNGesus,19,7,12
Kes,19,9,10
Magnitude,19,6,13
```

Comment: We can help more effectively if you provide for us the desired output and the output you are actually getting.  lacking that, my best guess is that you may be using `list.append()` when you actually want `list.extend()`

Comment: I'm trying to make sure the sorted list is only printed once and in order of higher to lower
Player Nickname      Matches Played       Matches Won          Matches Lost         Points
Esports.                    19                             8                              11                                 
24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses indents to delimit blocks. In your code, the printing loop is embedded in the reading loop.

Try the following:

```
myfile = open('Results.txt')
title = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20}'.format('Player Nickname','Matches Played','Matches Won','Matches Lost','Points')
print(title)
unsorted_data = list()
for line in myfile:
    item = line.strip().split(',')
    points = int(item[2]) * 3
    item.append (points)
    if item[2] != 0:
        unsorted_data.append(item)

sorted_data = sorted(unsorted_data,key=lambda x : x[4], reverse= True)
for item in sorted_data:
    result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:<20}'.format(*item)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/administrator/PycharmProjects/Kai Bin/Partial code test.py", line 12, in <module>
    sorted_data = sorted(unsorted_data,key=lambda x : x[5], reverse= True)
  File "/Users/administrator/PycharmProjects/Kai Bin/Partial code test.py", line 12, in <lambda>
    sorted_data = sorted(unsorted_data,key=lambda x : x[5], reverse= True)
IndexError: list index out of range
I got this

Comment: @MineFlamerKaiBin Shouldn't it be `lambda x: x[4]` if you want to sort by points since you only have 5 items.

Comment: ya, its suppose do be 4 sorry but its still giving me same error

Comment: Yeah, sorry I copy pasted your code without checking... If you are trying to access the 5th element, it is indeed item[4] since indices are zero based. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @MineFlamerKaiBin Print your unsorted list before sorting and check how many items each list has.

Comment: @MineFlamerKaiBin The current code seems to be working for me. Could you please detail your new error?

Comment: it outputted with a huge bunch of repeated names why though?

Comment: ah right Chris I found my mistake I did not change [5] to [4] thats why its giving me errors thks. But where can I put .rstrip to remove the escape codes on [3]

Comment: @MineFlamerKaiBin Did you make sure to de-indent the second for loop as suggested? In my case, the output seems normal with the input that you provided.

Comment: @MineFlamerKaiBin look at my answer for `strip`

Comment: @MineFlamerKaiBin I inserted the .strip() call as suggested by Steven.

Answer (score 0):

You are not clearing `unsorted_data` for each line so it uses the same list each time. Move it inside your for-loop so you create a new list each iteration

```
for line in myfile:
    unsorted_data = [] # can use [] instead of list()
```

Or just use your list (`item`) from `split` instead.

```
sorted_data = sorted(item,key=lambda x : x[4], reverse= True)
```

That is unless you want a list of all the data, move your for-loop outside the outer for-loop so it prints all the data at the end

---

As for the `\n` you want to `strip` before `split`.

```
item = line.strip().split(',')
```

Comment: could you like show me where to put it in Chris code